# MTOUCH : error MT2101: Can't resolve the reference 'System.IntPtr CoreFoundation.CFString::CreateNative(System.String)

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

I get the following error when I try to archive my Xamarin.IOS app for publishing:

MTOUCH : error MT2101: Can't resolve the reference 'System.IntPtr CoreFoundation.CFString::CreateNative(System.String)', referenced from the method 'System.Void Com.OneSignal.iOS.OneSignal::AddTrigger(System.String,Foundation.NSObject)' in 'Xamarin.iOS, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=123456789'.

Running the app on a simulator is working fine.

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: Which AppsFlyer iOS SDK version you are using now? Here is the same issue on the GitHub you can refer to [v6.4.0.1 Build Error](https://github.com/AppsFlyerSDK/XamariniOSBinding/issues/40).

Comment: I don't use the AppsFlyer IOS SDK. The error is for OneSignal

Comment: There could be several reasons for this error, such as an outdated version of Xamarin.iOS or a mismatch between the versions of Xamarin.iOS used on the build machine and the development machine. It’s also possible that there is an issue with the project configuration or references. You can try to update the Xamarin.IOS version.